# Android Studio Emulator does not show text as expected

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to learn android development. As you can see in the picture, I changed the original text"Hello world!" to "Hi!" and the change shows up on Preview(on the right side of the Android Studio) but not the emulator(I used Nexus 6). Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Clean and rebuilt your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having `cpp` subfolder under your `app` directory. Check the logic of files contained in `cpp` folder. I'm sure the string shown in emulator is set from `cpp` folder and not `java` folder.

Comment: You are right. I created a new project that does not include cpp support and it works. But could you explain why the emulator works in java but not cpp?